# How can i open PDF file from SdCard in my Application programmatically but not in device installed PDFViewer?

Tags: android, pdf, android-webview

I Have used many of library but those all are Useless , I have also check weather the PDF file  can be opened in Web-view By converting my **URI** to Html code using **ContenProvider** but that also isn't worked for me .

I have used libraries like

- **PDF Viewer**
- **MuPDF library**
- and many more...

So, please if anyone have faced this problem or have solution for this problem then Help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using PDFViewer library [PDFViewer](https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library)
All you need to do is to:

- Import PDFViewer project to your workspace (or use PDFViewer. jar file).
- Add it as library for your project.
- Define an Activity like follows:

  ```
  public class ViewerActivity extends PdfViewerActivity {
    public int getPreviousPageImageResource() { return R.drawable.left_arrow; }
    public int getNextPageImageResource() { return R.drawable.right_arrow; }
    public int getZoomInImageResource() { return R.drawable.zoom_in; }
    public int getZoomOutImageResource() { return R.drawable.zoom_out; }
    public int getPdfPasswordLayoutResource() { return R.layout.pdf_file_password; }
    public int getPdfPageNumberResource() { return R.layout.dialog_pagenumber; }
    public int getPdfPasswordEditField() { return R.id.etPassword; }
    public int getPdfPasswordOkButton() { return R.id.btOK; }
    public int getPdfPasswordExitButton() { return R.id.btExit; }
    public int getPdfPageNumberEditField() { return R.id.pagenum_edit; }
  ```

  }
- Call Activity like follows:

  ```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, FILE_PATH);
   startActivity(intent);
  ```

Where FILE_PATH is pdfFileLocation on your device. 
Mine was like

```
final String FILE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/test/com_handbook.pdf";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry i have used it, but sometimes it will display all contents from PDF and sometime it will display half of contents, inShort it will not
be concistant for diaplay contents.

Comment: @chiragpatel check outOfMemoryError

Comment: Sorry but i have checked it out posibilities for all ,and finaly i will prepare a class from PDF_Viewer library and convert MyPdfFile.pdf to bitmap and that one is the best option for this.
And than open that bitmap image from sdcard and i m diaplaying it in webview.
So, this way i have solved my problem and i can show my pdf file successfully...